# How to show a remote git log using PHP

Tags: php, html, git

I have created a website which is being hosted by one.com and is being used for a school project. I would like to show certain information (retrieved by the git log command) to our visitors. For this I have tried using PHP and the following script(also found [here](https://gist.github.com/latheesan-k/3490cb6ab522ca87f535)):

```
<?php
// Author: Ngo Minh Nam
$dir = "azureuser@drone7.cloudapp.net:/home/azureuser/git/drones/";
$output = array();
chdir($dir);
exec("git log",$output);
$history = array();
foreach($output as $line){
    if(strpos($line, 'commit')===0){
        if(!empty($commit)){
            array_push($history, $commit);  
            unset($commit);
        }
        $commit['hash']   = substr($line, strlen('commit'));
    }
    else if(strpos($line, 'Author')===0){
    $commit['author'] = substr($line, strlen('Author:'));
    }
    else if(strpos($line, 'Date')===0){
    $commit['date']   = substr($line, strlen('Date:'));
    }
    else{       
    $commit['message']  .= $line;
    }
}

print_r($history);

?>
```

According to the users that used the script it should work. Personally I believe that the problem, in our case, resides in the fact that one.com is hosting our website and Git is being hosted on a remote server that has been created by someone else in our project team and should be accessible by: azureuser@drone7.cloudapp.net:/home/azureuser/git/drones/

This results into the fact that chdir will only be able to find folders located in the hierarchy of our website.

Does anyone know how we can solve this problem and will be able to show information from the git log (from a remote server) on our website?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the git server?

Comment: Yes, I just asked my team member who has set up the server.

Comment: You could try using ssh2 extension to php like here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have `ssh` access to the remote git server, you can call the `git log -10` over a ssh connection. To call this command automatically you should use public key authentication.

```
ssh azureuser@drone7.cloudapp.net "cd /home/azureuser/git/drones/; git log -10;"
```

### Pure PHP

In PHP this would look like this:

```
$output = [];
exec(
    'ssh azureuser@drone7.cloudapp.net "cd /home/azureuser/git/drones/; git log -10;"',
    $output
);
```

**Notice**: The user executing this PHP script needs public key authentication on the remote server.

### ssh2 extension

As [piotrekkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089412/piotrekkr) has mentioned, if the server has the PHP ssh2 extension installed, you could use this to call command remotely

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('drone7.cloudapp.net', 22);

// Authentication. Use the return value of the function to determine if the login
// was successful.
// 
// Use either password ...
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'azureuser', 'password');

// ... or public key authentication
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(
    $connection,
    'azureuser',
    '/home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
    '/home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa'
);

// Call git log command on the remote server
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'cd /home/azureuser/git/drones/; git log -10;');

// Make stream blocking
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$lines = []

// We do not use `stream_get_contents` because of the possibly large output
while ($line = fgets($stream));
    $lines[] = $line;
}
```

For a more convinient access to the git repository, you could use a PHP git library like [gitlib](https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib). Consider this as food for thought.

Comment: Sadly, it appears that one.com doesn't support SSH2. We checked this by using the var_dump(extension_loaded('ssh2')); command and it returned false. We will now have a look at your suggestion for gitlib. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You are welcome :) Do you tried the "pure" PHP solution with a simple exec and public key auth?

Comment: @Redesign1991 Do you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. I've tried using all the different solutions but they all didn't work using one.com (since they don't support ssh2). After consulting another team member he decided to host the website on his server. Right now I'm able to use exec commands and receive the output. But there's still a problem, since our website is located within /var/www/html/drone7/ directory and I can't use the cd command to navigate to /git/drones where I have to exercise the git log command(I can use cd .. or cd /var,...). I have consulted our server guy but he has yet to respond.

Comment: I've been able to solve it currently by using these commands:

sudo git --no-pager log develop > log.txt
sudo mv log.txt /var/www/html/drone7/

Which isn't the best solution, but at least I'm able to display something